# Why I can not send data from my Matlab app(PC) to my Android tablet via Bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, matlab, bluetooth

by the way : i'm not english fluent, be gentle,
I'm trying to send data from my PC in my Matlab App to my Android App via Bluetooth.

I started to create a Server bluetooth on my android app :

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

/**
* Created by Ytysen on 28/04/2016.
 */

public class BluetoothReceiver extends Thread {
private BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
private AtomicBoolean stop;
private BluetoothListener bluetoothListener;

public BluetoothReceiver(BluetoothDevice device, BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter) {
    BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
    this.bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothAdapter;
    this.stop = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    mmDevice = device;
    try {
        tmp = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("ReconnaissanceFaciale", UUID.randomUUID());
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    mmServerSocket = tmp;
}

public void setBluetoothReceiver(BluetoothListener bluetoothListener) {
    this.bluetoothListener = bluetoothListener;
}

public void stopCom() {
    this.stop.set(true);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    BluetoothSocket socket = null;
    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    while (true) {
        try {
            socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            Log.d("Message","Passage 2");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Message","No Passage 2");
            break;
        }
        if (socket != null) {
            manageConnectedSocket(socket);
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
                Log.d("Message","Passage 3");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Message","No Passage 3");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}

private void manageConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket socket) {
    String msg = socket.toString();
    Log.d("Message","Passage 4");
    bluetoothListener.onMessageReceived(msg);
    try {
        sleep(30);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void cancel() {
    try {
        mmServerSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { }
}

public interface BluetoothListener {
    public void onMessageReceived(String message);
}
}
```

And i'm sending data on Matlab like that :

```
b = Bluetooth('LUC', 5);
fopen(b);
fprintf(b,'%s','Do you want to build a snowman ?');
fclose(b);
```

I can see my message in btsnoop_hci.log :
[btsnoop_hci.log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiGQK.jpg)

[image]

My android app never go through my try's in void run()...
Any ideas ?

In my "MyActivity", i did that :

```
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null)
     { 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pas de Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// Device does not support Bluetooth 
} 
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) 
{ 
mBluetoothAdapter.enable(); 
} BluetoothReceiver bluetoothReceiver = new BluetoothReceiver(device, mBluetoothAdapter); 
bluetoothReceiver.setBluetoothReceiver(this); bluetoothReceiver.start();
```

Comment: Have you tested that your BluetoothReceiver gets created properly, that the BluetoothAdapter and BluetoothDevice passed exist and are not null? Also you don't seem to have used "setBluetoothReceiver". It would be helpful to copy/paste the Log output you are getting.

Comment: After some time, i know that is the line :
`socket = mmServerSocket.accept();`
who waits something.